What is the RabbitMQ shovel equivalent in EMQX broker?
I am trying to copy messages from a remote EMQX broker to a local EMQX broker, running on my computer. I have access to both remote and local brokers. RabbitMQ has a plugin, called shovel, which does a similar job. It sends all data received by a remote RabbitMQ broker to a local RabbitMQ broker.
Is there a similar plugin for EMQX? How else could I route data received by the remote EMQX broker to the local one?

You should look at MQTT bridging
